# How to update a mongodb removing a duplicates using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have to generate a report based on some flags. My code will be as follows.

```
   var arrFail = [];
   for(r=0;r<res.length;r++){
   if(mflag != "1" && phone !="0" && src != false){
      //expresions
       if(clag && gflag && oflag && tflag){
           arrFail.push([res.num,"not ok"]);
        }
       else if(){
        //expressions

       }
    }
   else{
      arrFail.push([res.num,"phonefail"]);
    }
   }
  return arrFail;
```

Finally Im sending back this arrFail.So there I need to update the mongodb.

```
     const fail = async function(model,failedRecords,arrFail,Id){

for( var i=0;i < arrFail.length; i++ ){

    for( var j=0;j< arrFail.length; j++ ){

        var query = { PhoneNumbers : arrFail[i][j] , Id: Id };
        var set = { 'Status': 'Failed',FailureReason:arrFail[i][j+1] };
        model.updateMany(query,{ $set: set},async function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.log("er",err);
            }
            else{
               console.log("no error ",result);  
               return;
            }
        })

    }
}
```

}

So this is how I'm updating the mongodb. My problem here is if first if condition is a failure, I will send it back as `"phoneFail"` in the `arrFail` Array. If phonetype and mflag & src is a failure I need to send my failArray as `"phoneFail"`and  also `mflag,src failure`. I not only have 3 fags. I have 8 flags like this. How do I append to my array & send this to update mongodb?

Comment: It's hard to parse the question. Are you asking "how do I scale my current code that handles 3 conditions to handle 8 conditions?"

Comment: @nz_21  yes   . could you please suggest me some idea?